# After upgrade, LibreOffice uses wrong colors

Tags: upgrade, themes, libreoffice, 16.04

After upgrading from 14.04 to 16.04, I have a number of issues with LibreOffice. See this screenshot:

[image: illustration of LibreOffice problems]

Regarding the circled numbers on the screenshot:

1. Some interface elements, such as these tabs, the font color is nearly invisible.
2. The icons are difficult to see against the dark background. The default icons were much worse, but changing to Tango icons improved, but didn't fix, the problem.
3. The automatic font color is worse than before. See number 4.
4. Text using the automatic font color appears maroon. Previously, it was nearly black, which caused its own issues. This, though, is just ridiculous.

I'm using the default Ambiance theme. How can I fix these issues?

## Edit

A [bug report](https://bugs.documentfoundation.org/show_bug.cgi?id=92776) contains a solution for issue 1: Launch LibreOffice as follows, possibly via a wrapper script:

```
SAL_USE_VCLPLUGIN=gtk soffice
```

This does *not* solve the other issues I pointed out.

Comment: @DKBose: I've tried the other default themes. Radiance is better because it's a light theme and thus avoids most of the issues. However, I prefer a dark theme. I haven't installed any third-party themes.

Comment: Your bug report led me to a workaround for issue 1, edited in above. Thanks. The other issues remain outstanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These issues can be related to LibreOffice issues with gtk3. You can end up with screens that look like this:

[image: screenshot]

Or this

[image: screenshot]

You can fix this by using gtk2 with LibreOffice. To force LibreOffice to use gtk2 instead of gtk3 uninstall the `libreoffice-gtk3` package.

```
sudo apt-get purge libreoffice-gtk3
```

This worked for me on Ubuntu 16.04.4 with LibreOffice version: 5.1.6.2

NOTE: This is not the same as one of the other answers. The other answer instructs you to purge the *libreoffice-gtk* package. This answer instructs you to purge the *libreoffice-gtk**3*** package.

This answer was originally found on [Ubuntu Forums](https://ubuntuforums.org) on this thread marked [SOLVED] [Color scheme with LibreOffice 5.1.0.3](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2315061&p=13446388#post13446388).

Answer (score 2):

Trying to fix a similar problem with Libreoffice 5.0.3 in my Ubuntu 16.04 install I ran across this post:

- https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1777206

The solution was to uninstall libreoffice-gtk. When I uninstalled libreoffice-gtk apt-get removed libreoffice-gnome as well. After the packages were removed I exited libreoffice-calc and restarted it, came back with the default icon/color layout.

```
(20:21:41)--> apt-get purge libreoffice-gtk
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  libreoffice-gnome* libreoffice-gtk*
<snip>
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] 
(Reading database ... lots of files and directories currently installed.)
Removing libreoffice-gnome (1:5.0.3~rc2-0ubuntu1~vivid2) ...
Removing libreoffice-gtk (1:5.0.3~rc2-0ubuntu1~vivid2) ...
```

Comment: This solution does not work for me on stock 16.04.4 with LibreOffice Version: 5.1.6.2 nor does the solution added to the OP via edit. Neither  one makes any change.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this by doing the following:

```
sudo apt-get purge libreoffice-gtk* libreoffice-gnome

sudo apt install libreoffice-gnome
```

Maybe the reason in libreoffice-style-elementary package